# paginate() throws error while using having() while get() shows the results

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-query-builder, laravel-pagination

Code:

```
if ($request->going){
    if($request->lattitude && $request->longitude){
        $CurrentIplat = $request->lattitude;
        $CurrentIplon = $request->longitude;
        $ads1 = DB::table('ads')
        ->leftJoin('categories', 'ads.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->select(
            'ads.*','categories.category_name',
            DB::raw("( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('{$CurrentIplat}') ) * cos( radians( ads.Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( ads.Longtitute ) - radians({$CurrentIplon}) ) + sin( radians({$CurrentIplat}) ) * sin( radians( ads.Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance")
                )
        ->where('ads.domain',$this->domain)
        ->groupBy('ads.id')
        ->orderBy('distance') 
        ->having('distance','<','500')
        ->get();
            }
        }
```

Gives proper output.

While using paginate()

```
if ($request->going){
    if($request->lattitude && $request->longitude){
        $CurrentIplat = $request->lattitude;
        $CurrentIplon = $request->longitude;
        $ads1 = DB::table('ads')
        ->leftJoin('categories', 'ads.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->select(
            'ads.*','categories.category_name',
            DB::raw("( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('{$CurrentIplat}') ) * cos( radians( ads.Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( ads.Longtitute ) - radians({$CurrentIplon}) ) + sin( radians({$CurrentIplat}) ) * sin( radians( ads.Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance")
                )
        ->where('ads.domain',$this->domain)
        ->groupBy('ads.id')
        ->orderBy('distance') 
        ->having('distance','<','500')
        ->paginate(10);
            }
        }
```

It throws

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `ads` left join `categories` on `ads`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id` where `ads`.`domain` = nz group by `ads`.`id` having `distance` < 5000)
```

Comment: When you add the paginate part, the select reset to ` count(*) as aggregate ` to make the query paginate and the select raw where you include the distance doesnt exists

Comment: So, you mean select conditions do not work with paginate? I am confused. Can you please rephrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paginate()` function in Laravel, executes two queries:

1. First, to get records with given pagination limit like 10 in your
   case.
2. Second, to get total count of records according to given where
   conditions.

Problem is in second query where `count(*) as aggregate` is the only field selected and there is no field like `distance` to perform having operation.

Only `get()` function working because it executes only one query to get all records with given where conditions.

**Solution:** Use distance condition in `where` instead of `having` as it is more efficient. But here the same calculation of distance need to write again as where conditions do not work with alias. Code should be:

```
if ($request->lattitude && $request->longitude) {
    $CurrentIplat = $request->lattitude;
    $CurrentIplon = $request->longitude;
    $queryDistance = " ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('{$CurrentIplat}') ) * cos( radians( ads.Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( ads.Longtitute ) - radians({$CurrentIplon}) ) + sin( radians({$CurrentIplat}) ) * sin( radians( ads.Latitude ) ) ) ) ";
    $ads1 = DB::table('ads')
            ->leftJoin('categories', 'ads.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->select('ads.*', 'categories.category_name', DB::raw("$queryDistance AS distance"))
            ->whereRaw('ads.domain = ' . $this->domain . " AND $queryDistance < 500")
            ->groupBy('ads.id')
            ->orderBy('distance')
            ->paginate(10);
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect the error that I see when I try this method.

Comment: Updated Answer!

Answer (score 0):

When using `paginate` Laravel first launches

```
SELECT count(*)
```

query to get number of records, so because in this query you have also `having('distance', '<', '500')` obviously SQL doesn't know what is `distance` in this query. The solution here is either using manual pagination (more complex one) or to repeat distance definition twice:

```
$distance = "( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('{$CurrentIplat}') ) * cos( radians( ads.Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( ads.Longtitute ) - radians({$CurrentIplon}) ) + sin( radians({$CurrentIplat}) ) * sin( radians( ads.Latitude ) ) ) )";


if ($request->going){
    if($request->lattitude && $request->longitude){
        $CurrentIplat = $request->lattitude;
        $CurrentIplon = $request->longitude;
        $ads1 = DB::table('ads')
        ->leftJoin('categories', 'ads.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->select(
            'ads.*','categories.category_name',
            DB::raw($distance.' AS distance'))
        ->where('ads.domain',$this->domain)
        ->groupBy('ads.id')
        ->orderBy('distance') 
        ->having(DB::raw($distance),'<','500')
        ->paginate(10);
            }
        }
```

So as you see above `distance` column was extracted to `$distance` variable and then it's used twice - 1st time in `select` and 2nd time in `having`